# How to overlay two divs while centering one of them

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm learning HTML & CSS so I'm trying to copycat [Coder Manual](https://codermanual.com/).

I made a div for the background (I'll just use one color for now) and another div for the content of that first blue section with the logo, navigation, etc..

However, I can't make the content div overlay the background div without using something like:

```
#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

but that prevents me from centering the content div using:

```
#content {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

What should I do in such situation?

Edit: here's the html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <img alt="Coder Manual" src="https://codermanual.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div id="blue-div">
            &nbsp;     
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might be easier to follow your issue if your two snippets had some sample HTML in them to demonstrate the CSS issue - even if the background just uses a solid color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform` to center it like this:

1-With `position: absolute` in an element with a known `width`

```css
.center{
    height: 40px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    background: #ddd;
    position: relative;
}

.center img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px; /*the half width */
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1" width="40px"  height="40px" alt="LOGO">
</div>
```

2- With `position: absolute` in an element with an unknown `width`

```css
.center{
    height: 40px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    background: #ddd;
    position: relative;
}

.center img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1" width="40px"  height="40px" alt="LOGO">
</div>
```

3- Centering even vertically

```css
.center{
    height: 80px;
    background: #ddd;
    position: relative;
}

.center img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;    
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gijdH.jpg?s=328&g=1" width="40px"  height="40px" alt="LOGO">
</div>
```

Comment: Number 2 did it.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to help you, check this out for full information http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/  and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I do something like this:

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
}
.bg-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg bg-blue">
  <div class="content">
    <img alt="Coder Manual" src="https://codermanual.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

but if you need to keep the `div`s seperate:

```css
#BgBlue {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="BgBlue">
  &nbsp;
</div>
<div class="content">
  <img alt="Coder Manual" src="https://codermanual.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/logo.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! never knew that text-align centers everything and not just text lol.